# Is there a way to search for Cygwin packages by command, and then download the package, and all its dependents?

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin, qt

I'm currently trying to use a program called Paml, in Cygwin but to initially configure it I need to use the "qmake" command in a Cygwin which as far as I can tell, seems to be part of the qt5-tool package. This package seems to be a collection of qt5 packages that all have their own required packages, which in turn have packages that they require. Basically, I'm just trying to download a bundle of whatever I need to run qmake, so I can configure and run Paml, in Cygwin, on my Windows computer. I know that CIs there a way to search for linux emulator packages by command, and then download the package, and all its dependents? Cygwin packages are chosen and installed in the setup application. That much I can do. Also, I've been looking here: https://cygwin.com/packages/ To try to find the package that includes qmake. Searching "qmake" gives me 82 hits to various packages, that I guess include that term in their documentation, so I guess they're loosely related to it, with one or a few being the packages I actually need. I really feel like this isn't how I'm meant to be doing this. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cygcheck` to look for the proper program:

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/qmake
Found 20 matches for bin/qmake
libQt5Core-devel-5.9.3-2 - libQt5Core-devel: Qt C++ application framework (core
libraries)
libQt5Core-devel-5.9.4-1 - libQt5Core-devel: Qt C++ application framework (core
libraries)
libQt5Core-devel-5.9.4-2 - libQt5Core-devel: Qt C++ application framework (core
libraries)
..
```

of course you are not interested in QT4, QT3, debuginfo and mingw64 packages.
So you need to install `libQt5Core-devel` with Cygwin setup that will take care of all dependencies.
After that:

```
$ cygcheck -l libQt5Core-devel | grep qmake.exe
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake.exe
```